# Roblox Script Builder Sandbox

Tags: roblox

I recently started creating a script builder. The only part I am stuck on is getting the sandbox to work.

I tried following this tutorial: http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Sandboxing but with no avail

I didn't understand fully on how to do this, but I managed to go as far as this:

```
local needssandboxing = function(i) end

sandbox = {}
sandbox.cache = {}

local function safeDestroy(obj)
    if obj.ClassName == "Script" then
        print("You cannot destroy a Script")
    elseif obj == "Base" then
        print("You cannot destroy the Base.")
end 


    obj:Destroy()
end

local function safeGetChildren(obj)
    local res = {}

    for k,v in pairs(obj:GetChildren()) do
    if not v.Name:match("^Hide") then
            table.insert(res,v)
        end
    end

    return res
end

sandbox.mt = {
    __index = function(self, k)
        local original = sandbox.cache[self]
        local v = original[k]

        if k:lower() == "destroy" then
            return sandbox.any(safeDestroy)

        elseif k:lower() == "getchildren" or k:lower() == "children" then
            return sandbox.any(safeGetChildren)
        end

        return sandbox.any(v)
    end,

    __newindex = function(self, k, v)
        local original = sandbox.cache[self]
        original[k] = unsandbox.any(v)
    end
}

function sandbox.any(a)
    if sandbox.cache[a] then
        return a

    elseif type(a) == "function" then
        return sandbox.func(a)

    elseif type(a) == "table" then
        return sandbox.table(a)

    else
        return value
    end
end

function sandbox.object(o)
    local sandboxed = setmetatable({}, sandbox.mt)

    sandbox.cache[sandboxed] = o

    return sandboxed
end

function sandbox.func(f)
    local sandboxed = function(...)
        return sandbox(f(unsandbox(...)))
    end

    sandbox.cache[sandboxed] = f

    return sandboxed
end

function sandbox.table(t)
    local sandboxed = {}

    for k, v in pairs(t) do
        sandboxed[sandbox.any(k)] = sandbox.any(v)
    end

    return sandboxed
end

unsandbox = {}

unsandbox.any = function(a)
    if sandbox.cache[a] then
        return sandbox.cache[a]

    elseif type(a) == "function" then
        return unsandbox.func(a)

    elseif type(a) == "table" then
        return unsandbox.table(a)

    else
        return a
    end
end

unsandbox.table = function(t)
    local unsandboxed = {}

    for k, v in pairs(t) do
        unsandboxed[unsandbox.any(k)] = unsandbox.any(v)
    end

    return unsandboxed
end

unsandbox.func = function(f)
    local raw = function(...)
        return unsandbox(f(sandbox(...)))
    end

    sandbox.cache[f] = raw 

    return raw
end

local callable_mt = {
   __call = function(self, first, ...)
       if select('#', ...) == 0 then
           return self.any(first)
       else
           return self.any(first), self(...)
       end
   end
}

setmetatable(sandbox, callable_mt)
setmetatable(unsandbox, callable_mt)
```

But I don't know how to use it exactly. I tried:

```
sandbox(function() 
    local r = game.Workspace:GetChildren()
    for i=1, #r do
        print(r[i])
    end
end)
```

That does absolutely nothing. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, there is no function `sandbox()`, so you're trying to call a nonexistent function.

Try this:

```
sandbox.func(function()
    local r = game.Workspace:GetChildren()
    for i=1, #r do
        print(r[i])
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sandbox itself is not a function but the `__call` metamethod allows it to be called as a function even though it's a table.

Your code must be placed inside a Script with the following code.
Then when you wish to load a script, put a StringValue named "Code" inside the script with the Value property set to the script you wish to execute:

```lua
local realEnvironment = getfenv(0);
local fakeEnvironment = setmetatable({}, {__index = function (self, i)
    if (realEnvironment[i]) then --Check if object exists at all
        return sandbox(realEnvironment[i]) --return sandboxed object
    end;
end, __metatable = 'This is a locked metatable!'}); --An environment to only return sandboxed objects
setfenv(0,fakeEnvironment);--Set the global environment 
setfenv(1,fakeEnvironment);--Set the current function stack
assert(loadstring(script:WaitForChild('Code').Value))();
```

The final line waits for 'Code' child, then calls `loadstring` on it, assert will check if it has a syntax error and if it does it will error that, if not it returns the function which is then called (No need to set the ENV of the function because we set the global environments).